# How to model leaning columns in opensees?

Tags: civil-engineering, software, columns, earthquake-engineering

I want to modelling three buildings next to each other in opensees software . Duo to modelling leaning columns , buildings overlap with each other . Now my question is that for 3 adjacent buildings how can i consider leaning columns ?

Comment: Can you share an image or illustration of what do you want to do, please?

Comment: Thank you :) I found my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interference is graphical only, and since there are no common nodes, it is not a problem for the beams or columns to overlap with each other or intersect because the interactions are transmitted through nodes and elements, and it can be modeled normally